# Generate a join similar to a vlookup based on closest date

Tags: mysql, sql, query-performance

I have the following two tables:

`movie_sales` (provided daily)

- movie_id
- date
- revenue

`movie_rank` (provided every few days or weeks)

- movie_id
- date
- rank

The tricky thing is that every day I have data for sales, but only data for ranks once every few days. Here is an example of sample data:

```
`movie_sales`
- titanic (ID), 2014-06-01 (date), 4.99 (revenue)
- titanic (ID), 2014-06-02 (date), 5.99 (revenue)

`movie_rank`
- titanic (ID), 2014-05-14 (date), 905 (rank)
- titanic (ID), 2014-07-01 (date), 927 (rank)
```

And, because the `movie_rate.date` of `2014-05-14` is closer to the two sales dates, the output should be:

```
id         date             revenue           closest_rank
titanic    2014-06-01       4.99               905
titanic    2014-06-02       5.99               905
```

The following query works to get the results by getting the min date difference in the sub-select:

```
SELECT
    id,
    date,
    revenue,
    (SELECT rank from movie_rank where id=s.id ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF(date, s.date)) ASC LIMIT 1)
FROM
    movie_sales s
```

But I'm afraid that this would have **terrible** performance as it will literally be doing millions of subselects...on millions of rows. What would be a better way to do this, or is there really no proper way to do this since an index can not be properly done with a `DATEDIFF` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you are right. The movie rank table must be searched for each movie sale and of all matching movie rows the closest be picked.

With an index on `movie_rank(id)` the DBMS finds the movie rows quickly, but an index on `movie_rank(id, date)` would be better, because the date could be read from the index and only the one best match would be read from the table.

But you also say that there are new ranks every few dates. If it is guaranteed to find a rank in a certain range, e.g. for each date there will be at least one rank in the twenty days before and at least one rank in the twenty days after, you can limit the search accordingly. (The index on `movie_rank(id, date)` would be essential for this, though.)

```
SELECT
  id,
  date,
  revenue,
  (
    select r.rank 
    from movie_rank r
    where r.id = s.id
    and r.date between s.date - interval 20 days
                   and s.date + interval 20 days
    order by abs(datediff(date, s.date)) asc
    limit 1
  )
FROM movie_sales s;
```

Comment: thanks, I think since I'm only doing this query once per day (in a data load job) this query is the most maintainable without having to worry about a lot of the other factors that come up in a different approach.

Answer (score 1):

This is difficult to get quick with SQL. In a programming language I would choose this algorithm:

1. Sort the two tables by date and point to the first rows.
2. Move the rank pointer forward until we match the sales date or are beyond it. (If we aren't there already.)
3. Compare the sales date with the rank date we are pointing at and with the rank date of the previous row. Take the closer one.
4. Move the sales pointer one row forward.
5. Go to 2.

With this algorithm we would already be in about the position we want to be. Let's see, if we can do the same with SQL. Iterations are done with recursive queries in SQL. These are available in MySQL as of version 8.0.

We start with sorting the rows, i.e. giving them numbers. Then we iterate through both data sets.

```
with recursive
sales as 
(
  select *, row_number() over (partition by movie_id order by date) as rn
  from movie_sales
),
ranks as 
(
  select *, row_number() over (partition by movie_id order by date) as rn
  from movie_rank
),
cte (movie_id, revenue, srn, rrn, sdate, rdate, rrank, closest_rank) as
(
  select
    movie_id, s.revenue, s.rn, r.rn, s.date, r.date, r.ranking,
    case when s.date <= r.date then r.ranking end
  from (select * from sales where rn = 1) s
  join (select * from ranks where rn = 1) r using (movie_id)
  union all
  select
    cte.movie_id,
    cte.revenue,
    coalesce(s.rn, cte.srn),
    coalesce(r.rn, cte.rrn),
    coalesce(s.date, cte.sdate),
    coalesce(r.date, cte.rdate),
    coalesce(r.ranking, cte.rrank),
    case when coalesce(r.date, cte.rdate) >= coalesce(s.date, cte.sdate) then
      case when abs(datediff(coalesce(r.date, cte.rdate), coalesce(s.date, cte.sdate))) <
                abs(datediff(cte.rdate, coalesce(s.date, cte.sdate)))
           then coalesce(r.ranking, cte.rrank)
           else cte.rrank
      end
    end
  from cte
  left join sales s on s.movie_id = cte.movie_id and s.rn = cte.srn + 1 and cte.closest_rank is not null
  left join ranks r on r.movie_id = cte.movie_id and r.rn = cte.rrn + 1 and cte.rdate < cte.sdate
  where s.movie_id is not null or r.movie_id is not null
--  where cte.closest_rank is null
)
select
  movie_id,
  sdate,
  revenue,
  closest_rank
from cte
where closest_rank is not null;
```

(BTW: I named the column `ranking`, because `rank` is a reserved word in SQL.)

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e994cb56798efabc8f7249fd8320e1cf

This is probably still slow. The reason for this is: there are no pointers to a row in SQL. If we want to go from row #1 to row #2, we must search that row, while in a programming language we would really just move the pointer one step forward. If the tables had an ID, we could build a chain (next_row_id) instead of using row numbers. That could speed this process up. But well, I guess you already notice: this is not an algorithm made for SQL.

Comment: that's cool, I'd love to do this -- I should've tagged the question with mysql5.7, but yes this is a very nifty approach, thanks!

Comment: one question though, with `Sort the two tables by date and point to the first rows.`. Why would you do that first? Why not partition by the Movie title first and then sort by the date?

Comment: Well, I *am* partitioning by movie and sort by date. Only, a table is an unordered set of data by definition. A subquery result is again a table (only that it is not stored to disk but only exists in memory). So, while I can remember the order by numbering the rows, I will still have to search row #2 after being done with row #1, because #2 is not physically located after #1. This is the big drawback when trying to implement this algorithm in SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach...  Avoid the problem by cleansing the data.

Make sure the rank is available for every day.  When a new date comes in, find the previous rank, then fill in all the rows for the intervening days.

(This will take some initial effort to 'fix' all the previous missing dates.  After that, it is a small effort when a new list of ranks comes in.)

The "report" would be a simple `JOIN` on the date.  You would probably need a 2-column `INDEX(movie_id, date)` or something like that.

Comment: yes, that's what I'm currently doing actually. I'd prefer to do it all in SQL because some of the data updates in very odd fashions (backfilling ids...sales data coming in at different times than rankings, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Ultimate solution would be not to calculate all the ranks every time, but store them (in a new column, or even in a new table if you don't want to change existing tables).

Each time you update you could look for sales data without rank and calculate only for those.

With above approach you get rank always from last available rank BEFORE sales data (e.g. if you've data 14 days before and 1 days after, still the one before would be used)

If you strictly need to use ranking closest in time, then you need to run UPDATE also for newly arrived ranking info. I believe it would still be more efficient in the long run.